# Accounting/legal service for small part-time consultant

Tags: united-states, accounting, self-employment, consulting

I am starting part-time consulting in the U.S. on the side of my full-time job, mostly for fun (programming and web development). So far, I only completed one project and although I am marketing myself for more, it's not unlikely I'll keep hovering around 2 to 3 projects a year.

That was probably a mistake but since this was my first experience, I focused on making the client happy (and making sure I wasn't violating the terms of my full-time contract) more than on the legal aspects of me effectively taking on a second job.

Now that the job is done and the client is asking me for an invoice, I realize that there is more to the legal side of my fun little consulting gig, and frankly, I'd rather not have to deal with it.

For just a few projects a year I am mostly doing for fun, I don't want to get deep in the weeds of paperwork, licensing, and the like. And I would not mind if the money I take went down provided someone was dealing with that for me.

Are there any company/services out there that, for some fee (whether a cut of the contract or a flat fee) allow you to be "as carefree as an employee" when it comes to legalities, taxes, invoicing, etc. ?

What I mean is with my "regular" employer, I don't have to worry about taxes, business licenses, or billing the clients I am working for through my employer.

For my consulting work, is it possible to go through a third party that, for some fee, deals with all those things while leaving me the job of finding clients, negotiating rates and extent of projects, whether I want to take on a project or not, etc.

I realize what I am describing might not be all that clear. Feel free to ask for clarifications if it indeed isn't.

**To clarify**, I am *not* looking for explicit recommendations of a particular professional or company. I am more interested in the right keyword and distinctions between business titles that could carry services (or packages of services) like the ones I am looking for.

Not being from the U.S. originally, I don't even know where to start. Where I am companies offering similar bundles of services would be called "secrétariat sociaux" or maybe "coopérative d'indépendants" among other names. But I don't what the "equivalent" is for the U.S.

Comment: Such services do exist; as phrased this question might be viewed as 'recommend me a good service to do this', which would be off-topic. You may want to edit to solicit advice more along the lines of 'what should I look for when considering such services'.

Comment: It makes sense that questions like "recommend a good service for Y" are off topic here, thanks for pointing it out explicitly. I'll clarify the question on this point in a second.

Comment: I think the self-answer you provided is fair, and not spam. I don't think it needs to be deleted, but cannot vote to undue as it was deleted by a moderator. Anyway, glad to see you found resources.

Comment: @JohnFx Would you care to explain your deletion of the OP’s answer?

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica It was flagged as not an answer and I agreed. However, given how vague the question is it is hard to tell.  It might be a better edit to mhoran_posprep's answer or a comment

Answer (score 3):

I would start with a [small business development center](https://www.sba.gov/about-sba/sba-locations/headquarters-offices/office-small-business-development-centers) which is a program in the Small business administration:

> The U.S Small Business Administration (SBA) administers the Small
> Business Development Centers Program to provide management assistance
> to current and prospective small business owners. SBDCs offer one-stop
> assistance to individuals and small businesses by providing a wide
> variety of information and guidance in central and easily accessible
> branch locations.
>
> The program is a cooperative effort of the private sector, the
> educational community and federal, state and local governments. It
> enhances economic development by providing small businesses with
> management and technical assistance.
>
> There are now 62 Lead Small Business Development Centers (SBDCs) --
> one in every state (Texas has four, California has six), the District
> of Columbia, Guam, Puerto Rico, Samoa and the U.S. Virgin Islands --
> with a network of more than 900 service locations. In each state there
> is a lead organization which sponsors the SBDC and manages the
> program. The lead organization coordinates program services offered to
> small businesses through a network of subcenters and satellite
> locations in each state. Subcenters are located at colleges,
> universities, community colleges, vocational schools, chambers of
> commerce and economic development corporations.

You can [search by zip code](https://www.sba.gov/local-assistance/find?type=Small%20Business%20Development%20Center&pageNumber=1) for resources near you.

They can provide advice regarding how to get started and where you can find other resources.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this all-in-one service exists, because it includes accounting, insurance and legal services while excluding staffing services.

Your best bet may be to contract with a bookkeeper or CPA who is willing to oversee all of these services that will make you feel "as carefree as an employee."